# JavaFx TextArea does not popup keyboard

Tags: javafx-8, redhat

Application running on RedHat 7, touchscreen interface, written using JavaFX 8.
Keyboard has a 'lower keyboard' button.  If the user selects a TextField component, then lowers the keyboard, selecting the same (still focused field) will popup the keyboard again.

If the user selects a TextArea component, the keyboard is initially displayed. If they then lower the keyboard, and select the same (still focused text area), the keyboard will not display.

If focus is lost and then gained in the TextArea, the keyboard will display.

Why is this so, and how do I make the keyboard show whenever the field is selected?

Comment: Could you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little hackish but if I fully understand your question the following might work for you.

```
textArea.onTouchReleasedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<EventHandler<? super TouchEvent>>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends EventHandler<? super TouchEvent>> observable, EventHandler<? super TouchEvent> oldValue, EventHandler<? super TouchEvent> newValue) {
        if(newValue) {
            if(textArea.isFocused()) {
                    textArea.getParent().requestFocus();
            }

            textArea.requestFocus();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: A tweak of this worked, as on RedHat 7 'TouchEvents' are 'MouseEvents'